# Using replace in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query using replace

```
SELECT 
            replace(
            replace(
            replace(
            replace(
            replace(email_text , 'This email is to notify you that for one or more records the Clearance has been Requested. Please follow the link below to go directly to this record.', '') 
              , ':', '</th>:<th>')  
              , '<BR/></th>','<BR/>') 
              , 'http</th>:<th>', 'http:') 
              , '</ul>', '</th></ul>') 
            INTO  v_result 
                FROM   record.notification  
                WHERE record_notification_id = p_recordnotification_id;
```

in above code I have

```
replace(email_text , 'This email is to notify you that for one or more records the Clearance has been Requested. Please follow the link below to go directly to this record.', '')
```

Now instead I want to use like **replace email_text with the sentence that starts with  'This email'  and ends with 'this record.'**
instead of writing complete sentence .
Please suggest.

Comment: Grah, why?! What are you actually trying to do here - get the plain text out of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex:

```
regex_replace(email_text, 'This email.*this record[.]', '')
```